# How to get unique values for several different time ranges WHERE exec_datetime >= NOW() - INTERVAL n DAY?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select

I can select the total amount of unique ip addresses between a single time range

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ip_address) as ip_addr, exec_datetime
FROM requests
WHERE exec_datetime >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY;

ip_addr exec_datetime
45      12/10/2012 5:21
```

How do I return a result set for the following clauses in a single query...

```
WHERE exec_datetime >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY;
WHERE exec_datetime >= NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY;
...
WHERE exec_datetime >= NOW() - INTERVAL 14 DAY;
```

...so that the result set would look like this?

```
ip_addr exec_datetime
45      11/26/2012 5:21
85      11/27/2012 5:21
130     11/28/2012 5:21
170     11/29/2012 5:21
...     ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use something like this:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT requests.ip_address) ip_addr,
  days.day
FROM
  (SELECT now()-INTERVAL 1 DAY as day UNION
   SELECT now()-INTERVAL 2 DAY UNION
   ...
   SELECT now()-INTERVAL 14 DAY) days
  INNER JOIN requests
  on requests.exec_datetime >= days.day
GROUP BY
  days.day
```